# Pandas: Search and match based on two conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using the code below to make a search on a .csv file and match a column in both files and grab a different column I want and add it as a new column. However, I am trying to make the match based on two columns instead of one. Is there a way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("matchone.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("comingfrom.csv")

def lookup_prod(ip):
    for row in df2.itertuples():
        if ip in row[1]:
            return row[3]
    else:
        return '0'

df1['want'] = df1['name'].apply(lookup_prod)

df1[df1.want != '0']
print(df1)
#df1.to_csv('file_name.csv')
```

The code above makes a search from the column name 'samename' in both files and gets the column I request ([3]) from the df2. I want to make the code make a match for both column 'name' and another column 'price' and only if both columns in both df1 and df2 match then the code take the value on ([3]).

```
df 1 :

name price value
a     10    35
b     10    21
c     10    33
d     10    20
e     10    88

df 2 :
name price want
a     10   123
b     5    222
c     10   944
d     10   104
e     5    213
```

When the code is run (asking for the `want` column from d2, based on both if df1 name = df2 name) the produced result is :

```
name price value want
a     10    35   123
b     10    21   222
c     10    33   944
d     10    20   104
e     10    88   213
```

However, what I want is if both df1 name = df2 name and df1 price = df2 price, then take the column df2 `want`, so the desired result is:

```
name price value want
a     10    35   123
b     10    21    0
c     10    33   944
d     10    20   104
e     10    88    0
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question right, also your code doesn't work. If you want to check two columns in an ordered fashion, use `df1.done.equals(df2.done) and df1.aswell.equals(df2.aswell)`. Unordered you can iterate through both DataFrames via `for row1, row2 in zip(df1.itertuples(), df2.itertuples())`and make sure to encompass the entire column when checking a single value with in -> `if row1[1] in df2.done`. Does this help?

Comment: Have you considered using `pandas.DataFrame.merge()` method? For more help, could you please provide the samples of the dataframes?

Comment: ;Can you add a minimal reproducible example with expected output please?

Comment: @Nyquist I updated the code with a working example data frames with desired output.

Comment: @BorisSilantev I updated the code with a working example data frames with desired output.

Comment: @grymlin I updated the code with a working example data frames with desired output.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `pandas.DataFrame.merge()` method with multiple keys:

```
df1.merge(df2, on=['name','price'], how='left').fillna(0)
```

Method represents missing values as NaNs, so that the column's dtype changes to `float64` but you can change it back after filling the missed values with 0.

Also please be aware that duplicated combinations of `name` and `price` in `df2` will appear several times in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are matching the two dataframes based on the name and the price, you can use `df.where` and `df.isin`

```
df1['want'] = df2['want'].where(df1[['name','price']].isin(df2).all(axis=1)).fillna('0')

df1
  name  price  value   want
0    a     10     35  123.0
1    b     10     21      0
2    c     10     33  944.0
3    d     10     20  104.0
4    e     10     88      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on https://stackoverflow.com/a/73830294/20110802:

You can add the validate option to the merge in order to avoid duplication on one side (or both):

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name','price'], how='left', validate='1:1').fillna(0)
```

Also, if the float conversion is a problem for you, one option is to do an inner join first and then `pd.concat` the result with the "leftover" `df1` where you already added a constant valued column. Would look something like:

```
df_inner = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['name', 'price'], how='inner', validate='1:1')
merged_pairs = set(zip(df_inner.name, df_inner.price))
df_anti = df1.loc[~pd.Series(zip(df1.name, df1.price)).isin(merged_pairs)]
df_anti['want'] = 0
df_result = pd.concat([df_inner, df_anti]) # perhaps ignore_index=True ?
```

Looks complicated, but should be quite performant because it filters by set. I think there might be a possibility to set name and price as index, merge on index and then filter by index to not having to do the zip-set-shenanigans, bit I'm no expert on multiindex-handling.

Answer (score 0):

```
#Try this code it will give you expected results

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name' :['a','b','c','d','e'] ,
                    'price' :[10,10,10,10,10],
                    'value' : [35,21,33,20,88]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name' :['a','b','c','d','e'] ,
                    'price' :[10,5,10,10,5],
                    'want' : [123,222,944,104 ,213]})



new = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', left_on=['name','price'], right_on=['name','price'])

print(new.fillna(0))
```